# Inhomogenous wave equation: Waveguiding vs radiation problems

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, waveguide

I want to ask a general question about two vast topics of applied electromagnetics: Guided and unguided (radiated) waves.

I have noticed that there are almost always some common strategies for dealing with such problems.

For the guided waves (for example, the eigenmodes inside a waveguide), we usually write the (Helmholtz) wave equation in a source-free region. Mathematically, this means that we deal with the homogenous wave equation. Then, taking into account the boundary conditions, we find the modes of the propagating wave.

For radiated waves (for example when dealing with antennas), we use the magnetic vector potential $\vec{A}$, which satisfies the same wave equation, except this time we try to solve the inhomogenous equation, that is, we include the effect of the sources, which means that we solve it for points in space belonging to a region which possibly contains the sources. Finally, we get an expression familiar to those dealing with electromagnetic problems: $\vec{A(\vec{r})}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{V}\vec{J}(\vec{r}')/(|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|) dV $, where V is a region containing the sources.

My question is, why in waveguiding poblems we are working exclusively in source-free regions, ignoring any sources inside the waveguide, but in radiation problems we have to solve the inhomogenous wave equation for $\vec{A}$? I understand that, in a sense, waveguiding problems are essentially eigenvalue problems, which means that we are seeking for inherent field modes that can be supported by a certain structure, regardless the sources. Could we do the same in radiation problems? Could we just ignore any sources and solve the homogenous wave equation for $\vec{A}$, and then compute the fields from $\vec{A}$, working exclusively in the source-free region?

Thinking about it as I am writing this question, if we followed this procedure, we would not have any boundary conditions to determine any integration constants for the solution of the homogeous equation. We would have the radiation condition, imposed at $r=\infty $, but this probably would not be enough information for determining this integration constant... So, is this the real reason why we bother solving the inhomogenous wave equation, instead of solving the homogenous one?

Answer (score 1):

An axially homogeneous waveguide has a special discrete set of modes that can "propagate" (including evanescent modes, too) along its axis without dispersion. A suitable linear combinations of these modes can form almost any kind of possible solutions in the waveguide. (If the waveguide has a homogeneous cross section then it can be shown that the modes form a complete set.)

When a probe (antenna) is placed in the waveguide, say, to launch a wave then that wave can be decomposed into these modes, and given the frequency only a finite set of modes may have real wavenumbers, the rest will have imaginary wavenumbers representing a reactive load on the probe. In usual practice, one selects the frequency to have a single mode with real wavenumber, that mode represents the real load on the probe.

Such arrangement is much easier to analyze than having an antenna in open space because of the discreteness and uniqueness of these modes. First of all, the modes of open space form a continuous, that is a non-discrete set. Then there are many kinds: there are plane waves, spherical waves, cylindrical waves, etc. To form an actual wave from an antenna you must match the continuous sum (weighted integral) of such waves both to the antenna *and* the radiation condition (Sommerfeld). There is no *natural* way of doing this unlike in a waveguide where the complete set of modes is the *only* true possibilities.